# Base de datos por microservicio y relaciones entre ellas

Tags: python, base-de-datos, orm, sqlalchemy

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación sobre Python usando el framework de Flask. Está orientada a microservicios y cada uno dispone de su propia base de datos. Actualmente estoy en el proceso de creación de los modelos de uno de los microservicios empleando Flask-SQLAlchemy.

El tema es que, como es obvio, en la base de datos de este microservicio (responsable de gestionar incidencias) existe un punto de conexión con otro (responsable de gestionar aplicaciones) que es una tabla que relaciona ambos. Sin embargo, no sé como diseñar esta relación por estar las aplicaciones fuera del alcance del microservicio de incidencias.

Algunos compañeros me han sugerido que el ORM tenga noción de todas las bases de datos, que modele todas las entidades y relaciones y que los microservicios puedan acceder a las relaciones que únicamente les atañan. Sin embargo, considero que, de cara a largo plazo, no es buena idea dado que, en el caso de que exista un equipo por microservicio, todos tendrían noción de todas las bases de datos cuando realmente solo debe interesarles la de su microservicio.

Otros me han recomendado que simule la relación creando otro modelo como los que aparecen más adelante. Bajo mi punto de vista eso no es correcto puesto que se trata de una relación y no de un modelo. Es cierto que solventa el problema pero no de la manera correcta.

Algo de código para que se vea la problemática:

```
from base_class_sql import BaseModel
from app.models.emergency_alch_sql import Emergency
from main import db

class Incident(BaseModel, db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 't_incident'

    incident_id = db.Column(db.String(20), primary_key=True)
    incident_parent_id = db.Column(db.String(20))
    emergency_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(u't_emergency.emergency_id'), nullable=False, index=True)
    summary_incident = db.Column(db.String(200))

    # relaciones con otros modelos
    emergency = db.relationship('Emergency')

# t_inc_app es la tabla que relaciona las incidencias con las aplicaciones
inc_apps = db.Table('t_inc_app',
    db.Column('incident_id', db.String, db.ForeignKey('Incident.incident_id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('app_id', db.String, primary_key=True),   # columna extraida del microservicio de aplicaciones
    BaseModel.created_audit_date,
    BaseModel.updated_audit_date,
    BaseModel.user_audit_id
)
```

En este caso, la entidad `Emergency` se puede relacionar sin problemas con la entidad `Incident` dado que ambas existen en la misma base de datos. Sin embargo, `inc_apps` no puede relacionarse mediante la función  `db.relationship()` puesto que inc_apps es una instancia de la clase `db.Table` y no de `db.Model`.

Entiendo que esta problemática es bastante común trabajando con [bases de datos por microservicio](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/database-per-service.html) solo que no sé como crear la relación M a N cuando realmente el `app_id` no tiene importancia desde el punto de vista del microservicio de incidencias.

Comment: Hola, avanzaste en este tema? estoy en la misma situación y no encuentro mucha documentación al respecto. Gracias

Answer (score -1):

Lo que sugiero es que tu servicio de incidencias (db.Model) regrese el id correspondiente cuando se genera el registro en la tabla. Después capturas dicho id y lo envías muy probablemente por un segundo endpoint que apunta a tu segundo micro servicio (db.Table) y ahi formas la relación. Esto es recomendable hacerlo a través de un message queue que va a escuchar estos eventos y propagarlos de manera asincrona.

Comment: Cómo lo solucionaste? Gracias